# React useAuth hook not correctly providing user role for conditional rendering of buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern

I'm currently working on a React project where I have a JobListingsPage component. I'm using the useAuth hook from my AuthContext to handle user authentication. The goal is to conditionally render buttons based on the user's role (jobSeeker or employer).

Here's a snippet of my JobListingsPage component code:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import api from "../services/api";
    import { useAuth } from "../AuthContext";
    import "./JobListingsPage.css";

    const JobListingsPage = () => {
      const [jobListings, setJobListings] = useState([]);
      const { user } = useAuth();

      // ... other code ...

      return (
        <div className="job-listings-page">
          <h2 className="job-listings-title">Job Listings</h2>
          <ul className="job-list">
            {jobListings.map((job) => (
              <li className="job-listing" key={job._id}>
                {/* ... job details ... */}
                {user.role === "jobSeeker" && (
                  <button className="apply-button" onClick={() => applyForJob(job._id)}>
                    Apply
                  </button>
                )}
                {user.role === "employer" && (
                  <button className="edit-button" onClick={() => deleteJobListing(job._id)}>
                    Delete
                  </button>
                )}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default JobListingsPage;
```

Despite setting up the conditional rendering based on the user.role, the buttons are not appearing as expected. When I logged the user object, it seems to be an empty string ({}). I'm wondering if I'm missing something in my authentication setup or if there's an issue with how I'm using the useAuth hook.

Could someone please help me identify the potential issue here and guide me on how to properly retrieve the user object with the correct role so that the buttons are rendered according to the user's role?

Note: I've already checked that my AuthContext is providing the user object with the correct role, and I've followed the documentation for the useAuth hook.

Comment: We'll need to see how the useAuth hook is implemented, and we'll probably also need to see where you render an AuthContext.Provider.

Comment: also, just to check: `jobListings` is an empty array in your example. Can i assume that something in `... other code ...` fills it out to be non-empty?

Comment: I have made some huge mistakes. I wanted to use redux but think I am using context API without knowing. I am new to this and learning while doing so. Thank you.